# Sanity Studio: Parsing Error for Babel Preset Env

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, yarnpkg, sanity

I'm new to working with Sanity, and just set up a project. Everything is working fine, however, in Visual Studio Code, I keep getting a parsing error that won't disappear, and I'm wondering how I can fix it.

```
Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env'
```

I've tried deleting the `node_modules` and re-running `sanity install`, I've also tried using `npm install` to install `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-env`. Nothing seems to have fixed the problem so far.

Any suggestions? I want to start using Sanity with my team at work, but having this error is really quite annoying (as everything is underlined in red).

Answer (score 19):

I was having a similar issue. For me, the issue was related to the way VS Code deals with a project containing multiple ESLint working directories (common in monorepos).

For example

```
Project
   |--- /web
   |--- /studio
```

In my project root, edit (or create) `./.vscode/settings.json` to include my ESLint projects. NB: these settings only apply to your current workspace.

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./web", "./studio"]
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: It worked. It's better to add the setting to the workspace settings.

Answer (score 5):

Method 1:

Create a file called .babelrc in your root directory and add this code

```
    {
      "presets": ["next/babel"],
      "plugins": []
    }
```

And in .eslintrc replace the existing code with

```
    {
      "extends": ["next/babel"]
    }
```

Method 2:

You need to install npm with this command:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env

         or


npm install --save-dev @babel/core
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply edit(or create) a file in your project root called .eslintrc `./.eslintrc` and add this code:

```
{
  "extends": "@sanity/eslint-config-studio",
  "eslint.workingDirectories": ["./web", "./studio"]
}
```

To solve this issue you can just be setting a working directory for your project. It's a major improvement in eslint version 2.0.4.

Sometimes, need to customize the working directories via eslint.workingDirectories can now use glob patterns instead of listing every project folder. For example, { "pattern": "code-*" } will match all project folders starting with code-. In addition, the extension now changes the working directory by default.

You can also explore the eslint doc: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint