# Parsing Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env' for Sanity

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, sanity

For a React project, I installed Sanity under the schema folder and then I started adding different JS files into it, but even though there is no code in them, I get the error in the header for each js file.

I also tried

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
```

but it didn't work.

[image]

I started to watch Clever Programmer's Uniswap video but I cannot move forward with the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didn't write any code. I just install npm and sanity cli

Comment: I’ve answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71686078/882733) which may help you.

Answer (score 12):

In your Sanity folder, you can add this code to the .eslintrc file:

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./web", "./studio"]
```

So it should be like this:

```
{
  "extends": "@sanity/eslint-config-studio",
  "eslint.workingDirectories": ["./web", "./studio"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved it. You might need to change your webpack.config file. Go to:

```
node_modules/react-scripts/config
```

and open your *webpack.config.js*. Inside this file search for babel options and add this preset:

```
presets: [
  [
    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
    {
      runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
    },
  ],
],
```

so your webpack.config file should look like

```
test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
include: paths.appSrc,
loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
options: {
customize: require.resolve(
  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
),
presets: [
  [
    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
    {
      runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
    },
  ],
],
// @remove-on-eject-begin
babelrc: false,
configFile: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In my case,
this command is working now
**"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./web", "./studio"]**

after adding this command project will working

Answer (score -1):

You can just change your .eslinc files into:

```
["next/babel", "next/core-web-vitals"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).